# How do I grant a user permissions to specific Azure services (as you can with AWS's IAM)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-iam

I've tried reading different guides and documentation about Azure users and roles, but nothing looks similar to IAM on AWS.

Where I can **limit users to use only certain services** in the Azure console/portal?

Could someone provide me with a link to the relevant documentation or describe to be a way to do this (if it is possible to do)?

Thanks for everyone time by the way.

Comment: Azure RBAC Overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview. Azure RBAC Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal. HTH.

Comment: Will try it right now and edit with results, thank you!

Comment: @GauravMantri You can add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure provides this functionality through [`Role Based Access Control (RBAC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview). Using RBAC, you can provide granular permissions to  users, groups or applications (also known as Service Principal) in your Azure AD. Azure provides a number of [`in-built roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) that cover a variety of scenarios. It also provides you an ability to create [`custom roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) if an in-built role does not suit your requirements.

You can learn more about RBAC here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview.

Azure Portal provides a comprehensive user experience for managing RBAC. You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal.